# «Для» или «за»? – This store is for the purchase of

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, узус

I was writing a paragraph, and a sentence within (and the previous sentence) is, in English:

> (The first store sells mostly bulk produce.) The second store is (a) traditional (store), for the purchase of general household goods and foods.

to which I translated as,

> Втор**о**й магаз**и**н традици**о**нный (магаз**и**н), за пок**у**пкой **о**бщих дом**а**шних тов**а**ров и прод**у**ктов.

My tutor said it was better to say,

> Втор**о**й магаз**и**н традици**о**нный, там м**о**жно куп**и**ть **о**бщие дом**а**шние тов**а**ры и прод**у**кты.

or if I insisted on my English-sounding translation (which I don't),

> Втор**о**й магаз**и**н традици**о**нный, для пок**у**пки **о**бщих дом**а**шних тов**а**ров и прод**у**ктов. (of which after the nominalized verb I use plural genitive instead of accusative)

---

I understand there are 'ways' people say things, so I accept the "There one can buy" impersonal construction, but my question is, "**why для пок**у**пки instead of за пок**у**пкой**?".

I myself have used these resources for `for` in English;

- https://www.alphadictionary.com/rusgrammar/for.html
- [Difference between "за" (as in "за что-либо/кого-либо") and "для"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12288/difference-between-%d0%b7%d0%b0-as-in-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be-and-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f)
- ["for the benefit of", на благо vs для?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15514/for-the-benefit-of-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be-vs-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f)

but the problem is to translate the use of `for` even.... For example, the 2nd link's accepted answer would (to me) imply **за**, corroborated by point 3 in the first link.

However, point 2 of the first link validates my tutor's claim, as does the 2nd point in the accepted answer of the 2nd link.

Comment: I don't like the word "традиционный" here. It has a stronger connotation of "folk" or "old" than in English. Better to say "обычный" instead. We also don't use the word "general" in this sense ("общий") that much: it's better to drop it altogether in this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“*За покупкой*” is a wrong choice to translate “for the purchase” in that sentence, “(store), *for the purchase* of general household goods and foods”.

“*За покупкой*” is “*за*” + **Instrumental case**, which is quite different from your link to [Difference between "за" (as in "за что-либо/кого-либо") and "для"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12288/difference-between-%D0%B7%D0%B0-as-in-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-and-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F) which deals with за + **Accusative case**.

“*За покупкой*” (“*за*” + **Instrumental case**) is about the aim, goal, usually used with **verbs of motion** (**came** to buy): “*Он **пришёл** сюда за покупкой*” – “He **came** here for a purchase / to buy something”. Here “за покупкой” is an **adverbial modifier of purpose** (Came here for what purpose? – To buy something).

In your sentence, “(store), “*for the purchase of general household goods and foods*”, “*for the purchase of general household goods and foods*” is an **attribute** (What kind of store? – A store *for the purchase of general household goods and foods*), so it cannot have **за** + **Instr.** after it; **для**  + **Genitive case** (“for”) is used instead, as it was suggested to you: “магазин традиционный, *для покупки* общих домашних товаров”.

Other ways of translating that phrase, “(store), “*for the purchase of general household goods and foods*” include

• магазин, ***где** продаются домашние товары* (“store **where** household goods are sold”)

• магазин *домашних товаров* (“store **of** household goods”)

Comment: aaahhh pt 6 of the first link is "за" + instr, and with a verb of motion.... I can understand using genitive for attributes (e.g. as in writing out dates in full)... is anything attributive cast in genitive as a rule of thumb? The "adverbial modifier of purpose"...gramaren.ru/grammar/gt/the-types-of-adverbial-the-modifier ... oh, these are just adverbs.. thanks :)

Comment: Bare genitive (i.e. a noun phrase in the genitive case **without** a preposition) is the typical attribute thing (_сестра **моей жены**_ “**my wife's** sister”).  But there are lots of prepositions that need the Genitive case after them, not all of them mark true attributes, “_для **моей жены**_ “for _my wife_”, “_от **моей жены**_ “from _**my wife**_”, etc.